# What's wrong with this Title Page?

Tags: titles, mdframed, line, page, frame-title

I'm having troubles in setting up a simple title-page.

1. Some horizontal lines aren't drawn at the proper place, one on top of the next (see the preview below).
2. I would like to add a white border all around the page, where the printer can't print the background color.
3. I would like to add a thin black line (rectangular frame) all around the page, delimiting the background color and the white border.

Here's the MWE code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype,lmodern}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

\pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

\centering

\newlength{\titlelength}
\settowidth{\titlelength}{\Huge\scshape Some Main Title}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\rule{\titlelength}{1.6pt} \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\titlelength}{0.4pt} \\[\baselineskip]

{\Huge\scshape Some Main Title} \\[\baselineskip]

{\large\slshape Subtitle} \\[0.2\baselineskip]

\rule{\titlelength}{0.4pt} \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\titlelength}{1.6pt} \\[4\baselineskip]

{\Large\scshape Name} \\

\vfill

{\large\scshape Version Number}

\par

\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \maintitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Preview of the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal lines should be stacked one on top of another, and be exactly of the same lenght as the main title.

How can I fix and simplify the code above, and add a rectangular frame with a white border on its exterior side?

Comment: You're lacking a blank line between both.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You mean Im missing \\ ?  Yes it appears to fix the issue #1.

Comment: A blank line introduces a new paragraph. You also can use ``. In  each case, check whether the paragraph indent interferes.

Comment: Well, using \\ \vspace*{... appears to fix my issue number 1. Is that the proper way to do this?

Comment: It's one of the proper ways. You might interested by a look at the documentation of the `titling` package, which provides some tools to customise `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 2):

Nice !  I found a simple way to add a nice frame using the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype,lmodern}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160,180,200}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup

\pagecolor{backgroundcolor}

\centering

\newlength{\titlelength}
\settowidth{\titlelength}{\Huge\scshape Some Main Title}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\rule{\titlelength}{1.6pt} \\ \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\titlelength}{0.4pt} \\[\baselineskip]

{\Huge\scshape Some Main Title} \\[\baselineskip]

{\large\slshape Subtitle} \\[0.2\baselineskip]

\rule{\titlelength}{0.4pt} \\ \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\titlelength}{1.6pt} \\[4\baselineskip]

{\Large\scshape Name} \\

\vfill

{\large\scshape Version Number}

\par

\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \maintitle

   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
       \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
       \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]